# login reputation points not moved shared for (sqa) stack exchange, stack overflow and server fault

Tags: discussion

Should your reputation be ported over to these 3 different sites if you log in as the same OpenID?  I thought since the look and feel were similar in nature for these 3 sites, my reputation and badges would move as well.  Does anyone know?  Or did I choose the wrong option when I created my account?

Comment: sorry, I couldn't find a good tag for this post

Comment: You need to link your accounts.  Not posting as answer as should be meta question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome, Mr. Wanta!

Your accounts are linked, so you are eligible for the one-time rep bonus. However, you need to have 200 or more rep on one site to get it, and it appears you currently have 115 on StackOverflow, which is your highest rep.

But fear not, the rep comes easy, and in all honesty pales in comparison to the knowledge these guys on SQA.se have to offer! :-)

I hope that makes sense, it's early on a Sunday! :-)

Comment: I'd give you a point but I need a reputation of 15 or higher.  ;-)

Comment: That's alright. I have more rep than I need :) Besides, you don't get rep on the meta sites - they're synched with the primary site. I know it can be frustrating when you're on a site and you want to contribute more but you don't have the rep to, but don't worry, it will come quickly. 15 rep is 2 answer or 3 question upvotes, which is pretty darned easy to get :)